How to disable NGINX default welcome page for a specific site
We have an API which clients call back to our office over the internet using a specific non-standard port to a specific subdirectory on the hosting server. Currently, when you go to the site without using the subdirectory (but still using the non-standard port), it shows the default NGINX welcome page. How can I disable the welcome page from being shown in any case for this specific site, while still permitting the API calls to get through?
Here is my reverse-proxy.conf for this site:
server {
   listen (port number) ssl;
   server_name (site.domain.tld);
   ssl_certificate  (cert/path);
   ssl_certificate_key  (key/path);
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   location (subdirectory/path) {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_ssl_certificate (cert/path);
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key (key/path);
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://(local hosting server):(port number);
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
}

We are running this on Ubuntu server
I have tried looking for documentation about how to set this online and in the NGINX documentation, but I don't think I'm familiar enough with the terminology used for this setting.

The location / { ... } block matches any URL to that server block that is not already handled by another location. You could simply add a return 403; to deny access.
